# Lambda using OR in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm still fairly new to Lambda and I can't figure out how to write a Lambda expression that is similar to SQL..

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE ((date = todaysDate AND status = 'Paid')
       OR
       (paymentType = 'Visa' AND status = 'Pending'))
```

I can get one clause using Lambda not both.  This is what I have..

```
payments = scheduledPayments.GetAll().Where(x => x.date == todaysDate
                                           && x.status == 'Paid');
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Be wary - from the code given, it looks like you're asking the SQL server for *all* scheduled payments, and *then* applying a filter in memory. It all depends on what `GetAll()` does, and what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
payments = scheduledPayments.GetAll().Where(x => 
   (x.date == todaysDate && x.status == "Paid") || 
   (x.paymentType == "Visa" && x.status == "Pending") 
);
```